# Reason for multiple bars in Legend entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am have a similar Grouped Bar Chart as shown in  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164519/grouped-bar-colors-in-pgfplots) and wish to know why there are multiple bars in the legend entry. Is it possible to modify the legend so as to consolidate these bars?
[image: Legends with two bars]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The legend image code for `ybar legend` is defined as (page 212 chapter 4)

```
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em) (2*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em)};},
},
```

It is nothing but a bar plot with two coordinates, so you get two bars. By consolidating, if you mean to have a single bar, you may redefine it like

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
        (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},
   },
}
```

to get

[image]

or simply remove the second coordinate as in

```
\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
            plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em)};},
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
        /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
        %\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
                %(0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},
        \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
                plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em)};},
},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Population,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar=5pt,% configures ‘bar shift’
bar width=9pt,
nodes near coords,
point meta=y *10^-7 % the displayed number
]
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6)
(1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6)
(1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)};
\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what ##1 means? I understand that it allows something to become a parameter after the initial macro is expanded, but what becomes the parameter in this case?

Answer (score 8):

To fix this, just add style **`area legend`** *after* `xbar` or `ybar`.

The documentation for it says that it sets:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    legend image code/.code={
        \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
    },
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: It is recommended to explain with some more detail how such brief answers could be right according to the OP's request and for the benefit of the community. You can improve your answer with codes, images, links and step-by-step explanations.

Comment: I don't know why this works, or how it works, but this seemed simpler :)