# Legend problem with horizontal bars in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have a problem with a weird offset with horizontal bars in a pgfplots legend. They seem to be moved "up" a bit, so a part of them is hidden under overflow. An image of the situation which explains it quicker:

[image: the picture with legends]

Minimal TeX to reproduce (I am compiling with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    enlargelimits=0.25,
    legend style={},
    symbolic y coords={A,B,C},
    ytick=data,
    y tick label style={rotate=90},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(2.5,A) (5.1,B) (5.1,C)};
\addplot coordinates {(7.1,A) (5.4,B) (8.7,C)};
\addplot coordinates {(6.5,A) (5.0,B) (2.0,C)};
\legend{legend1, legend2, legend3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Q: How do I get the correct image of the horizontal bars? Expected output for me is to have the two vertical bars just like in other bar-style legends from pgfplots, e.g. in the question here: [Reason for multiple bars in Legend entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224676/reason-for-multiple-bars-in-legend-entries)

Q: or is it correct this way? If so, is it possible to modify the "thumbnail" to show something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

With the new [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) version 1.13 the code of the OP works as expected:

[image]

So if you can use version 1.13 the workaround in the answer below is not needed anymore.

---

**Original answer** (used with version 1.12):

As you can see in the documentation or in the `pgfplots.code.tex` the `xbar legend` image is defined by

```
/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
  /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
    \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
    plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em)(2*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em)};}
}
```

But I think the `x` and `y` coordinates should be interchanged:

```
/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
  /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
    \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
    plot coordinates {(0.8em,0cm)(0.6em,2*\pgfplotbarwidth)};}% <- changed
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
      \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
      plot coordinates {(0.8em,0cm)(0.6em,2*\pgfplotbarwidth)};}% <- changed
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    enlargelimits=0.25,
    %legend style={},
    symbolic y coords={A,B,C},
    ytick=data,
    y tick label style={rotate=90}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(2.5,A) (5.1,B) (5.1,C)};
\addplot coordinates {(7.1,A) (5.4,B) (8.7,C)};
\addplot coordinates {(6.5,A) (5.0,B) (2.0,C)};
\legend{legend1, legend2, legend3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. I will check if pgfplots already have this fixed upstream and report if not.
EDIT you filled it already at http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/100/ , thanks again :]